# Getting Json file objects into a dataframe

Tags: r, json, parsing, dataframe

Hello I am trying to get certain parts of a json file as columns of a dataframe and I have tried different packages but I keep getting different types of error such as:

```
Error in data.frame(df, dfone, dftwo) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

or

```
Error in rbind(df, dfone, dftwo) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'
```

Here is my code:

```
df = c(x$CVE_Items$cve$affects$vendor$vendor_data)

dfone = c(x$CVE_Items$cve$problemtype$problemtype_data)

dftwo = c(x$CVE_Items$cve$description$description_data)

df_1 <- data.frame(df,dfone,dftwo)
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have also tried `rbind`, `smartbind`, `rbind.fill` etc ...

Comment: you need to look at the `class()` of the three objects. are they vectors? are they lists? are they data.frames?

Comment: you might want to look at the jsonlite package which allows to read json format files; from there you should be able to select the columns you're interested in;

Comment: thanks @Mark that actually helped! df,dfone and df two are lists and I was trying to combine them assuming they are data frames